# EDIT: How to protect index.php/admin url using htaccess

Tags: magento-1.9, url, .htaccess, password

As accurate answers still not showing up, I had to take the alternative to remove `index.php` from `http://example.com/index.php/admin`

Below is my code at the top of `.htaccess file`

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/index.php/admin/
RewriteRule ^index.php/(.*) $1 [R=301,QSA,L]
```

I have written below code at the bottom of `.htaccess file`

```
<Files admin>

 AuthUserFile /var/www/magento/.htpasswd
 AuthName "Private access"
 AuthType Basic
 require user dummyuser

</Files>
```

**Problem:** Currently it successfully blocked the `URL` `http://example.com/admin` but not `http://example.com/index.php/admin`.

Also `index.php` is removed from `http://example.com/index.php/admin` but not from `http://example.com/index.php/admin/` with `/`

I am using `Magento 1.9.2.4`

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to do this using the combination of mod_env and the `Satisfy any` directive. You can use `SetEnvIf` to check against the `Request_URI`, even if it's not a physical path. You can then check if the variable is set in an `Allow` statement. So either you need to log in with password, or the `Allow` lets you in without password:

```
# Do the regex check against the URI here, if match, set the "require_auth" var
SetEnvIf Request_URI ^/index.php/admin require_auth=true

# Auth stuff
AuthUserFile /var/www/htpasswd
AuthName "Password Protected"
AuthType Basic

# Setup a deny/allow
Order Deny,Allow
# Deny from everyone
Deny from all
# except if either of these are satisfied
Satisfy any
# 1. a valid authenticated user
Require valid-user
# or 2. the "require_auth" var is NOT set
Allow from env=!require_auth
```

Comment: I dnt need to block from ip,I just need to password protect

Comment: @Hiranya check my edited ans

Comment: It's not working.

Answer (score 0):

Besides adding an extra password protection through the htaccess. I recommend to change the admin key this can be done in through configuration in the system admin section or in the local.xml